# include a binded folder for each new users created

Tags: ftp, bind

In a nutshell, my ftp server consists of 2 folders for each individual users. so *john* has this on his directory

```
/home
  +/john
     +/pub   <-- binded to /var/ftp
     +/private
```

my public folder is `binded` with `/var/ftp/` to `/home/john/pub`.

each time i create a user, i need to bind my `/var/ftp` to the `/home/newuser/public`
and do it over and over again when i create user.

How can I automatically create a `/pub` folder (binded to `/var/ftp`) for each new user?

This is how command when I create a new user with home directory

`/usr/sbin/adduser -g ftpgroup -d /home/mark mark`
it create `/home/mark`

I know this can be done, I just don't know how.

Comment: Can we assume with **binding** you mean making a (soft) link (`ln -s`)

Comment: ...and not `mount --bind` (which would be possible for one user only). You should edit your post and improve the wording (to e.g. "linked"/"symlinked").

Answer (score 1):

Normally the files from /etc/skel are copied when a new account is created.
So when you do the following as root (once):

```
cd /etc/skel
ln -s /var/ftp pub
```

Doing so you create a link that will be copied into the new user home directories as well.